# CSS - Setting image-size in the Outlook browser

Tags: c#, html, css, sharepoint, outlook

I am trying to create a news Homepage for clients to use in their Outlook homepage browser.

So far I have the below, which works in IE and Chrome and I am happy with the results:

As you can see, the thumbnail images are not being contained within the divs any more (looks like the `background-size: cover;` setting is not working in Outlook).

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving the same result in Outlook but without using the `background-size: cover` property? Code is at the bottom. Thank you

IE etc:

[image]

Outlook:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="article">

        <div class="imageBox">

        </div>

        <div class="articleWrapper">
            <h1> New Starter in PICN </h1>

            <p> Monday, December 7, 2015 </p>

            <p> We are delighted to welcome Joe Bloggs ... </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider">
    </div>

    <div class="article">

        <div class="imageBox">

        </div>

        <div class="articleWrapper">
            <h1> New Starter in PICN </h1>

            <p> Monday, December 7, 2015 </p>

            <p> We are delighted to welcome Joe Bloggs ... </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider">
    </div>

    <div class="article">

        <div class="imageBox">

        </div>

        <div class="articleWrapper">
            <h1> New Starter in PICN </h1>

            <p> Monday, December 7, 2015 </p>

            <p> We are delighted to welcome Joe Bloggs ... </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;

    width: 100%;    
    height: auto;
}

.topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightgray;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}

.pinkbar {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;    
    background: pink;
}

.pinkbar h1 {
    margin: 10px;
}

.imageBox {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(img/image1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.article {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.divider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: lightgray;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by retrieving the correct items from the SharePoint site.

In my C# code where I extract the images, adding `?RenditionID=6` to the end of the URL before saving as an image locally returned the thumbnail style I required (In this case I needed it to be a square - as it is displayed ont he main SharePoint page).